# Trying to build a data frame from an existing one with means of selected column and rows

Tags: r, dataframe

saving community,
I have a data frame with a HUGE amount of data. I would show you but the site is not letting me so I'll do my best to describe it. I have columns like this :

Participant   Task   Language   f0st

Under participant I have names (18 different names but duplicated), under task I have 3 different ones (reading, narration, conversation), under language there's 2 options (FR, ENG) and under f0st I have all the numeric values of f0 (the voice fundamental frequency) in semitones, that were extracted from recordings every 1ms (hence the huge amount of data).

So from these "raw" values, I want to build another data frame with a single mean value for each participant in each condition. So instead of hundred thousands of rows I end up with 18 rows corresponding to the number of participants.
For example to build the column in the new data frame with the mean f0st for each participant, in the reading task, in FR, how do I code this?

I hope this is clear enough! Thanks a bunch for your help :)

@maarvd : this is the input

```
structure(list(rowNumber = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), rowLabel = c("IPU1", 
"IPU1", "IPU1", "IPU1", "IPU1", "IPU1"), SampleTime = c(1.317302056, 
1.327302056, 1.337302056, 1.347302056, 1.357302056, 1.367302056
), F0 = c(238.4728491, 238.4728491, 238.4728491, 238.4728491, 
230.4871243, 235.301327), mother = c("french", "french", "french", 
"french", "french", "french"), level = c("bil", "bil", "bil", 
"bil", "bil", "bil"), name = c("clemence", "clemence", "clemence", 
"clemence", "clemence", "clemence"), task = c("film", "film", 
"film", "film", "film", "film"), lang = c("fr", "fr", "fr", "fr", 
"fr", "fr"), f0st = c(94.7721745186803, 94.7721745186803, 94.7721745186803, 
94.7721745186803, 94.1825081930544, 94.5403877585993), gender = c("F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), f0stnorm = c(1.11260538951537, 1.11260538951537, 
1.11260538951537, 1.11260538951537, 0.934191841072306, 1.0424743738019
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In my desired output there would be only one occurence of "clemence" since I would have only one mean value for her in each condition. It would be something like :

```
structure(list(name = c("clemence", "juliette", "maud", "jay", "daniel", "pilo"), reading_task_fr = c(94.7, 92.8, 90.2, 83.5, 85.6,86.7), reading_task_eng = c(93.4, 91.2 etc.), film_task_fr = c(...)
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: please show sample input data using dput(head(dt)) and your desired output.

Comment: Please make a working "desired output". I can't rund your second structure code, your first code lacks two closing `)`.

Comment: I guess, you are looking for something like `df %>% group_by(name, lang) %>% summarise(mean = mean(f0st))` using `library(dplyr)`.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to make a working desired output!! Ok let's try something more simple. In my current data frame, could you tell me how to ask R for the mean of one participant, in one task, in one language? I tried `mean(rawdataST$f0st[rawdataST$name == "clemence" , rawdataST$task == "film" , rawdataST$lang == "fr"])` but I got this error message : "Error in rawdataST$f0st[rawdataST$name == "clemence", rawdataST$task ==  : 
  incorrect number of dimensions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your problem you could use

```r
library(dplyr)

rawdataST %>%
  group_by(name, task, lang) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(f0st))
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   name, task [1]
  name     task  lang   mean
  <chr>    <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 clemence film  fr     94.6
```

If you don't want to drop the other columns, replace `summarise` with `mutate`.

---

A base R solution could be

```r
aggregate(f0st ~ name + task + lang, data=rawdataST, mean)
```

which returns

```r
      name task lang     f0st
1 clemence film   fr 94.63527
```

Comment: Ok, this helps a lot, I'll make do using this for now. Thank you so much @Martin Gal !!

Comment: Actually there is a problem, I created a data frame using your code but weirdly some values are missing. I should have a total of 108 rows (18 participants * 6 conditions) and I only have 97. Any idea why?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the data. Perhaps not every participant has every possible combination of task and language? You can check every unique combination by `rawdataST %>% select(name, task, lang) %>% distinct()`.

Comment: Ok I was able to identify which combinations are missing but I still don't understand why. I guess that's a completely different question so I'll still accept your answer. Thanks again for your help :)